# How to extend the page editor?

Tags: php, functions, save-post

I'm really a newbie to WordPress.

I can edit the page via admin Page menu. There is a form submitted on that page. How can I write my own functions to handle this form submission?
In other words, how could WordPress recognize the route in form ACTION, and forward to my functions? Use a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I think the batter way is to use plugin.

Check this : http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=form&sort=

I personally suggest you [Contact Form 7](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/)

Just past form plugin short code in your page/post , that's it !
Cheers !